# A verb that gives a very close meaning to stubborn?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

You're arguing with someone and they just refuse to give in to the truth, even though you just have this inkling that they're aware of the truth. They're just so opinionated and unyielding. I usually include the verb for stubborn in my language in this instance.(I could use the adjective, but that's the main reason for this question).

I know there isn't a verb for stubborn but is there any verb that gives a close meaning of stubborn?

the verbs insist, opinionate, stickle and other synonyms of these don't really do it for me. There has to be something out there that alludes to stubbornness.

Comment: Can you write the sentence with a blank?

Comment: oppose? contend? dispute? grapple? feud?

Comment: obstinate comes to mind, but it's not a verb...

Comment: If something connotes/denotes a condition (cold,hot, steady,stubborn, intelligent, stupid), how can there be a verb for that? Verbs cannot usually replace words for conditions or states.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider the verb ***persist***

Defined by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persist) as:

> to go on resolutely or stubbornly in spite of opposition, importunity, or warning

And [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/persist) as:

> 1. Continue in an opinion or course of action in spite of difficulty or opposition.

"*She persisted in saying the boat was full even when we showed her the empty seats.*"

Answer (score 2):

There's an expression which *includes* a verb: to dig in one's heels.

Comment: This may be the best verb equivalent available. In the context of an argument, we tend to express the idea of stubbornness in action (if that's not a contradiction in terms) with phrases such as "doggedly resist" or "remain unmoved by" or "be impervious to" appeals to reason.

Answer (score 1):

**to stand pat**

Definition
*1.(mainly US & Canadian) to refuse to abandon a belief, decision, etc
collinsdictionary.com*

Also:

to persist

to perseverate

to stick to one's guns

Comment: to persevere, not perseverate. Prevaricate.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with something poetic, you can use the verb **stubborn**. It's a pretty rare verb, but its meaning is pretty clear because everyone knows what the adjective stubborn means. You can find it defined in the Oxford English Dictionary as:

> Only *poet*[*ic*]
>
> *transitive*. To make stubborn; to harden, make firm, render capable of resistance.

(Note however that this page has not yet been updated. It looks like it's still the version that was first published in 1919.)

I found some examples online:

> Because he was too close to the mark for comfort, she'd stubborned up and refused his request.
>   <sub>[Expecting the Doctor's Baby](https://books.google.com/books?id=g736iAcV-M4C&q="stubborned")</sub>

> For the most part, though, I stubborned on. I still carried that river- rock weight in my bones, I was tired every day, but I'd just harden my head to a numb, and if nothing else, the grief would hang off to the side, like it had that first day digging ramps.
>   <sub>[Strange as This Weather Has Been: A Novel](https://books.google.com/books?id=n-ESui5QjwgC&pg=PA95&dq="stubborned")</sub>

> They eyed each other, then Dar finally laughed. "Yeah." She shook her head. "He still out stubborns me, though."
>   "Damn straight," Andrew agreed instantly.
>   <sub>[Eye of the Storm](https://books.google.com/books?id=BzGpVuydhtwC&q="stubborns")</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I believe **obstinate** would be useful here
Meaning:

> 1. Firmly or stubbornly adhering to one's purpose, opinion, etc.; not yielding to argument, persuasion, or entreaty.
> 2. characterized by inflexible persistence or an unyielding attitude; inflexibly persisted in or carried out:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/obstinate

Comment: Good word, not a verb as OP asks for, though.

Answer (score -1):

How about indurate? I am also very keen to know a "verb synonym" of stubborn. Indurate means hard, not sure that we can use it in this context.

Comment: Same comment as here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207234/a-verb-that-gives-a-very-close-meaning-to-stubborn/258074#comment1126146_258074

Comment: obdurate, not indurate.

Comment: Indurate is an uncommon word.  See the reference https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indurate ("indurate" can be a verb meaning "to make or grow hard," "to make unfeeling, stubborn, or obdurate,")